# Поиск папки на определенном уровне ssh

Tags: ssh

Как сделать поиск папок на определенном уровне.
Конкретный пример:
Есть папка /www/
Нужно по такой схеме поискать папку core

```
/www/*/data/www/*/core
```

И вывести пути к ним.

Comment: а термин *ssh* какое отношение имеет к вопросу?

Comment: А почему он не имеет значение? ну давайте напишу так: Как найти папки на сервере по такому шаблону используя SSH?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>не совсем ясно, к чему упомянут термин *ssh*, потому как к сути вопроса он явно не имеет никакого отношения.</sub>

при использовании программы *find*:

- с помощью опций `-mindepth` и `-maxdepth` можно указать минимальную и максимальную глубину поиска
- а с помощью теста `-type` можно ограничить тип искомого объекта.

итого:

```
$ find /www -mindepth 5 -maxdepth 5 -type d -name core
```

---

доп. чтение: `$ man find`